# Have the special filters stopped working?

Tags: bug, filtering

I usually search for non-accepted non-closed newest questions in Java with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=[java]%20hasaccepted%3a0%20closed%3a0) url.

Nowadays it seems to be including closed questions and questions with answers. Is this deliberate? Am I doing it wrong? It certainly seemed to work when I started using that technique.

Comment: Strangely, now I have posted the questing and checked the link it seems to work. It certainly wasn't before I posted. Strange!!

Comment: If you manage to repro, can you screen-shot it?

Comment: Ctl F5 after a few minutes and now I see [Java Program to read a html page and save its HTML code in a text file \[closed\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13176405/823393) in the list.

Comment: And now it's gone! Perhaps it's a cacheing issue. If the search results list is cached but each entry in it is re-rendered against live data you'd get this kind of issue. e.g. Search results cached for 5 minutes but question is closed after 2 then the closed question will persist until the cache is refreshed but the question will render as closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nick assures me that this is due to delayed indexing (every 15 minutes) on searches that are done via lucene. So: if something changes from closed/not-closed in that window, it may be considered (as far as the actual search is concerned) incorrectly. When we know the data we want to show, we then show the *actual* state, without re-applying the filter to the UI.

We could potentially investigate a post-filter scan, to remove any that don't actually match when it comes to the UI. We already do this for our tag-based searches (if they have been deleted etc while we weren't looking).

Comment: Sounds like what I am seeing. :) Your call to add the post-filtering.